# How to cast varchar to boolean

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I have a variable 'x' which is varchar in staging table, but it is set to boolean in target table which has 'true' and 'false' values. How can I convert varchar to boolean in postgresql?

Comment: Do you want to insert, select update? Or what?

Comment: I would like to Update

Answer (score 23):

If the varchar column contains [one of the strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-boolean.html) (case-insensitive):

- `t`, `true`, `y`, `yes`, `on`, `1`
- `f`, `false`, `n`, `no`, `off`, `0`

you can simply cast it to boolean, e.g:

```
select 'true'::boolean, 'false'::boolean;

 bool | bool 
------+------
 t    | f
(1 row)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9046).

Comment: This is not true, see `select 'true'::varchar::boolean, 'false'::varchar::boolean;`

Comment: What's wrong with it?? [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/17922)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I would have sworn that I've seen an error in new PostgreSQL as well, but it seems that this is only an issue in Redshift and old PostgreSQL versions.

Comment: Confirm that redshift will throw an error with `select 'true'::varchar::boolean;`: Invalid operation: cannot cast type character varying to boolean;

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work in redshift

Comment: [Redshift is not Postgres.](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AOaemvI4t3ELsDXj7GP8QlNfHx2d8QJmMg:1641982990147&q=redshift+vs+postgres&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd--qm_6v1AhWVyosKHaWbA_AQkeECKAB6BAgBEDc)

Answer (score 12):

For Redshift, I had the best luck with the following:

```
SELECT DECODE(column_name, 
             'false', '0', 
             'true', '1'
             )::integer::boolean from table_name;
```

This simply maps the varchar strings to `'0'` or `'1'` which Redshift can then cast first to integers, then finally to boolean.

---

A big advantage to this approach is that it can be expanded to include any additional strings which you would like to be mapped. i.e:

```
    SELECT DECODE(column_name, 
             'false', '0', 
             'no', '0', 
             'true', '1',
             'yes', '1'
             )::integer::boolean from table_name;
```

---

You can read more about the DECODE method [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DECODE_expression.html).

Comment: I am not seeming to need the intermediate `::INTEGER::` cast. `SELECT DECODE(col_name,
             'N', '0', 
             'Y', '1'
)::BOOLEAN FROM table_name;` is working fine for me in Redshift.

Answer (score 4):

In aws redshift unfortunately @klin answer doesn't work as mentioned by others. Inspired in the answer of @FoxMulder900, `DECODE` seems the way to go but there is no need to cast it to an integer first:

```sql
SELECT DECODE(original, 
  'true', true,   -- decode true
  'false', false, -- decode false
  false           -- an optional default value
) as_boolean FROM bar;
```

The following works:

```sql
WITH bar (original) AS
  (SELECT 'false' UNION SELECT 'true' UNION SELECT 'null') -- dumb data
SELECT DECODE(original, 
  'true', true,   -- decode true
  'false', false, -- decode false
  false           -- an optional default value
) as_boolean FROM bar;
```

which gives:

| original | as_boolean |
| --- | --- |
| false | false |
| null | false |
| true | true |

I hope this helps redshift users.

Answer (score 3):

For old PostgreSQL versions and in Redshift casting won't work but the following does:

```
SELECT boolin(textout('true'::varchar)), boolin(textout('false'::varchar));
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/17923) also see the discussion on the [PostgreSQL list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050615143124.GC7595%40wolff.to).

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume anything besides `true` is `false`, then you could use:

```
select
  column_name = 'true' column_name_as_bool
from
  table_name;
```