# default for column "xxxx" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean in Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update a column in brs.parts table from character varying to boolean.
The column has data as Y/N till now.
I am using the below command

```
ALTER TABLE brs.parts ALTER COLUMN is_dpm_scanned TYPE BOOLEAN USING is_dpm_scanned::BOOLEAN
```

---

But I am getting the following error:

********* Error **********

```
ERROR: default for column "is_dpm_scanned" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean
SQL state: 42804
```

---

The table definition was:

```
CREATE TABLE brs.parts (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    webcrt_part_id INTEGER,
    event_id INTEGER,
    webcrt_job_id INTEGER,
    incoming_serial_number CHARACTER VARYING(256),
    outgoing_serial_number CHARACTER VARYING(256), 
    part_number CHARACTER VARYING(256),
    tag_number NUMERIC,
    is_dpm_scanned CHARACTER VARYING(1) DEFAULT 'N'::CHARACTER VARYING,
    current_operation_id INTEGER,
    creation_date DATE,
    created_by CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL,
    last_updated_date DATE,
    last_updated_by CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL,
    is_delete CHARACTER VARYING(1) DEFAULT 'N'::CHARACTER VARYING
);
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You have to drop the default constraint before changing the type:

```
ALTER TABLE parts 
    ALTER COLUMN is_dpm_scanned DROP DEFAULT,
    ALTER COLUMN is_dpm_scanned TYPE BOOLEAN USING is_dpm_scanned::BOOLEAN,
    ALTER COLUMN is_dpm_scanned SET DEFAULT FALSE;
```

See also:

- [Changing a column from string to string array in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14782402/1995738) for a detailed explanation.
- [How to cast varchar to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688128/1995738).

Answer (score 4):

If casting an integer column to boolean you need to specify explicitly what values are considered `true` and what are `false`. Usually, 0 is mapped to `false` and everything else to `true`. To do this execute:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER mycolumn TYPE bool USING 
  CASE WHEN mycolumn=0 THEN FALSE 
  ELSE TRUE 
END;
```

Comment: Obviously, you **don't** need to use `case`. Casting integers to boolean works in Postgres as expected.