# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "imagesync__c" is of type boolean but expression is of type character varying

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using **WSO2 Report Mediator** to insert records to postgreSql Table. facing issue like **column "imagesync__c" is of type boolean but expression is of type character varying**

FYI,

- DataType for the column "**imagesync__c**" is **bool** and using **DBeaver 6.1.2**

  ```
  <property name="syncFlag" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
  <dbreport description="Insert into product2">
              <connection>
                  <pool>
                      <dsName>jdbc/QRSagAppSyncDataSource</dsName>
                  </pool>
              </connection>
              <statement>
                  <sql><![CDATA[INSERT INTO vonbibra_dev.product2(productcode,db_lastmodifiedbyuser,imagesync__c,sourcename__c)VALUES(?, ?,?,?,?)]]></sql>
                  <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="CarSales"/>
                  <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="qrsintegration"/>
                  **<parameter type="VARCHAR" expression="get-property('syncFlag')"/>**
                  <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="CarSales"/>
              </statement>
    </dbreport>
  ```

I have tried some casting which are mentioned below for that particular column, unfortunately none of them is working.

- **Casting ways**

  ```
  <parameter value="select get-property('syncFlag')::boolean" type="VARCHAR"/>
  <parameter value="CAST(get-property('syncFlag') as BOOLEAN)" type="VARCHAR"/>
  <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="1"/>
  <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="SELECT DECODE(get-property('syncFlag'), 'false', '0', 'true', '1' )::BOOLEAN"/>
  ```

**References:**

[CAST Function](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/casting-in-postgresql-570)

[TypeCasting](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-do-type-casting-in-postgresql/)

[Cast VARCHAR to BOOLEAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687830/how-to-cast-varchar-to-boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved my Issue by **CASTING in sql Query instead of Input parameter**.

```
<property name="syncFlag" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
<dbreport description="Insert into product2">
            <connection>
                <pool>
                    <dsName>jdbc/QRSagAppSyncDataSource</dsName>
                </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
                <sql><![CDATA[INSERT INTO vonbibra_dev.product2(productcode,db_lastmodifiedbyuser,imagesync__c,sourcename__c)VALUES(?, ?,?,?::BOOLEAN,?)]]></sql>
                <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="CarSales"/>
                <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="qrsintegration"/>
                **<parameter type="VARCHAR" expression="get-property('syncFlag')"/>**
                <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="CarSales"/>
            </statement>
  </dbreport>
```