# Redshift can't cast text to boolean from json field

Tags: amazon-redshift

In a Redshift database, given a field containing the following json:

```json
{"0":true,"1":true,"2":true,"3":true,"4":true,"5":true,"6":true}
```

Although I can extract `true` using `json_extract_path_text(my_field, '0')`, when I'm trying to extract an element and cast it to a boolean as follow:

```sql
SELECT 
    json_extract_path_text(my_field, '0')::boolean
FROM my_table
```

I then get the following error:

> cannot cast type text to boolean

I do not understand as the following is working without any issue:

```sql
SELECT 'true'::boolean, 'false'::boolean;
```

Comment: What does `SELECT json_extract_path_text(my_field, '0') FROM my_table` return for that row? `true`?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how to double check the type of it though, but according to the error it seems like a text

Comment: Can you cast to text and then to boolean?  Just a thought. My guess as to what is happening is that the value is sometimes not defined and that is "missing" value is not mapping to boolean. You may need to massage these "undefined" values to null with a decode() function.

Comment: I have a minimal example that reproduce the problem: `select json_extract_path_text('{"0":true}', '0')::boolean;`. If I cast to `text` before, I have a slightly different error: `cannot cast type character varying to boolean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post seems to answer the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45799072

```sql
    SELECT BOOLIN(TEXTOUT(json_extract_path_text('{"0":true}', '0')));
```

Comment: It seems that now it is not supported for redshift.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad thing with `json_extract_path_text` function. But as a workaround to this specific usecase, you can use the `case` statement as below:

```sql
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN json_extract_path_text(<json_field>, '<element>') = '1' THEN true
    WHEN json_extract_path_text(<json_field>, '<element>') = '0' THEN false
    ELSE null
END AS <field_alias>
FROM my_table
```